# Can you disambuguate a specific noun from a general noun with たち

Tags: grammar, plurals

A person was talking about living near a particular mountain. I want to say:

> I want to live near the mountains too

where I mean mountains in general, not the specific one he is talking about.
If I say:

> 私も山の近くに住みたい

will it sound like I want to live near his mountain? How do I make the distinction? I thought explicitly making it plural might be one way:

> 私も山たちの近くに住みたい

Does this work? Are their better/other ways?

Comment: What do you mean by "the mountains"? Is it specific 山脈, 連山 or 山地?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the pluralization of 山 is just 山. たち is reserved more for people/animals unless you are personifying inanimate object/things. See: [this question.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25231/plural-form-with-%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A1-%E3%82%89?rq=1)

Your sentence is fine to say that you want to live near mountains.  If you wanted to express the particular mountain that the person was talking about you could say for example:

> 私も**その**山の近くに住みたい